# Node-Red proper formatted output with template

Tags: database, templates, insert, node-red

I try do apply a template in node-red to generate a DB INSERT statement. One value to insert is a JSON-string.

if I apply inside template `INSERT ... VALUES ('{{time}}','{{data}}' ...` and display it in console I see:

```
INSERT INTO fuere4bfi.soma(itime,data,url) VALUES ('2020-03-25 10:03:33.651', '{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;Default&quot;,&quot;IsValid&quot;:true,&quot;TimeStamp&quot;:-1,&quot;AverageTemperature&quot;:96.3067853411676,&quot;WallTemperature&quot;:150.415780138639,&quot;Matrix&quot;:[[150.4,150.4,150.4,150.4,...
```

How can I get rid of the `&quot;`?

If I do the same without template, I get:

```
INSERT INTO fuere4bfi.soma(itime,data,url) VALUES ('2020-03-25 10:06:16.854', '{"Name":"Default","IsValid":true,"TimeStamp":-1,"AverageTemperature":96.3067853411676,"WallTemperature":150.415780138639,"Matrix":[[150.4,150.4,150.4,...
```

and this is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a Template node using the mustache formatting.

By default, the mustache template format will escape any special HTML characters. To stop that behaviour you use `{{{triple-brackets}}}`.